# profile is not updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

you can download this project from this link .https://drive.google.com/file/d/1daW4veZAI21b8TqKFHauSFTboHKJceaG/view?usp=sharing
Execute this Program Clicking on button"Click here to sell your Gold now" enter the

username :hermon_yonaito@bullionscope.com

password :Wau2017?

On selecting "Profile" the ProfileViewController.m is executed.On updating the user profile updateButtonTap function is executed.**It does not update.It remains buffering.How to perform profile update?**

here is updateButtonTap from ProfileViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)updateButtonTap:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    [selectedValues setObject:@"ios" forKey:@"request"];
    [selectedValues setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentUser.user_id] forKey:@"user_id"];
    [selectedValues setObject:postalAddressTextfield.text forKey:@"address"];
    [selectedValues setObject:mobileTextfield.text forKey:@"user_mobile"];
    [selectedValues setObject:question1Textfield.text forKey:@"user_answer_1"];
    //[selectedValues setObject:question2Textfield.text forKey:@"user_answer_2"];
    [selectedValues setObject:villageTextfield.text forKey:@"user_village"];

    [GeneralWebservices webserviceCallWithData:selectedValues webserviceName:Webservice_ProfileUpdate dataToPost:imageData imageName:imageName OnCompletion:^(id returnDict, NSError *error) {
        if ([returnDict[@"success"] intValue] ==1)
        {
//            UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
//            [alert setTitle:@"Updated Successfully"];
//           // [alert setMessage:@"Updated Successfully"];
//            [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
//            [alert show];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
            [alert setTitle:@"Updated Successfully"];
            //[alert setMessage:returnDict[@"message"]];
            [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
            [alert show];
        }
        [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];

    }];
}
```

Comment: can you please explain your problem area in detail

Comment: the issue is with if ([[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] isReachable])  checking. every time its failing. comment this line and try. Profile will get updated.